# Using background-image with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to solve an issue with my own css stylesheet along with bootstrap. I'm trying to have an image set as a background image on my index page, but can seem to display it.

CSS in my stylesheet:

```
.main-image{
    background-image: url(img/studio.png);
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section class="row main-image"></section>
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding 100% width/height won't work here, because the parent of the element doesn't have static dimensions.

Instead of using height/width: 100%, use 100vh and 100vw.

- 1vh - Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport.
- 1vw - Relative to 1% of the width of the viewport.

So your code has to be:

```css
body { margin: 0 } /* Removed the default body margin */

.main-image{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-image: url('http://www.superedo.net/wallpapers/wallpapers/Android%20Tablet/Huawei%20Mediapad%2010%20Fhd/huawei_mediapad_10_fhd_005.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="row main-image">
   <!-- -->
</section>
```

Comment: it weirdly appears in edge and IE but not in chrome, how strange lol

Comment: Hmm.. can u post a screenshot?

Comment: I had to clear the cache in my browser, weird where the css updates but the output on the screen didn't but thanks for your help everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define what space the image should be in

[Fiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/3x1g6obh/5/)

```css
.main-image{
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%; /* responsive */
    background-image: url('https://www.prestigeanimalhospital.com/sites/default/files/08-cat-cancer-4.jpeg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 100% 50%;
}
```

```html
<section class="main-image"></section>
```

You can control what is shown with `background-position: 100% 50%;`

100% is X - the horizontal value.

50% is Y  - the vertical value.

Or do it with `background-position-x` and `background-position-y`

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work, I'm trying to add my own styles in with Bootstrap. Quite tricky in all fairness.

Comment: nothing appears even if there is content within the div / section tags.

Comment: the url's that were added as an example were not pulling through, I'll have a much better look when I get home. Might resort to using the <img> tag instead of holding it in the css.